# Running Jupyter notebook with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

So I installed the latest version of Anaconda, then created an environment with python 3. To ensure that python 3 is actually the one recognized I first activated the environment then typed `python` below is what I got

```
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

So now that I made sure I already have python 3, I tried to run `Jupyter Notebook` however it seems to only have a python 2 kernel. And the kernel is not even linked to a specific environment as show in the image below

[image]

How can I add python3 kernel ? and why was not it recognized in the first place ?

Comment: You probably did not install Jupyter in the Anaconda environment, so another installation is used. Type `where Jupyter` in the shell to see which executable is run.

Comment: I would suggest you update your python version to 3.6.0

Install jupyter notebook with pip/pip3
`pip3 install jupyter` or `pip install jupyter`

A good practice is to create a new folder to test jupyter notebook.

In command line, type `jupyter notebook`, then a browser will prompt out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks everyone for answering but my issue was a little different.
When creating my environment I did not add the `anaconda` option

So instead of

```
$ conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

I used

```
$ conda create -n py35 python=3.5
```

According to [this](https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html?highlight=python) conda documentation, the `anaconda` option is

> the meta-package that includes all of the actual Python packages
>   comprising the Anaconda distribution

Still I could not relate why missing that option will not install python 3 kernel for Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I ended up installing jupyter with pip3 to get the python3 kernel.